# how to retrieve data from database(connection string is in App.Config file) to combobox in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

I am trying to load mssql server database table (one column) value to a combo box... But I couldn't.. I have given the Connection String in App.Config file. So I'm finding difficulties in retrieving column values to the combo box.

The following is the code that I used.

```
  private void StockInventoryManager_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbcategory.Items.Clear();
        SqlCommand cmd = dcon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Cat_name FROM Category";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            cmbcategory.Items.Add(dr["Cat_name"].ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: What difficulties you are having? Use try catch block, you might be getting exception.

Comment: You don't need a Command You can go with: SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("YOUR QUERY", connectionString)

Comment: Can you please be more specific about _I couldn't_? You get any exception or error message? You didn't get any data? Did you check your connection string is right? You don't need `ExecuteNonQuery` part by the way.

Comment: Can you check if dt.Rows.Count is greater then 0 ?

Comment: i get the error in the class file I have created named as DataControl, after running the application. 
    SqlCommand cmd = dcon.CreateCommand();
in the above code, that CreateCommand is generating a method in DataControl file and after running, in the DataControl file only shows the error